# How to initiate a std::thread calling a function that expects a function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

I have a class member function that I wish to run in a std::thread and it expects a function as a parameter, as follows:

```
ModbusAgent::poolingThread(int position, std::function<int(int, uint16_t*)> readFunction)
```

So the question is: how can I instantiate a std::thread for calling that?

Comment: Don't you think this Question that you posed and Answered yourself is best suited for [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)?

Comment: What's special about a function parameter? It's just another parameter.

Comment: Using a lambda would be much easier

Answer (score -2):

So here is the way I found for doing that:

```
class A {
public:
    int bar(int, uint16_t*) { return 0; }

    void foo(int position, std::function<int(int, uint16_t*)> readFunction) {
            readFunction(position, nullptr);
    }

    void b() {
        std::function<int(int, uint16_t*)> readFunction = std::bind(&A::bar, *this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
        std::thread(&A::foo, this, 5, readFunction);
    }
};


int main() {
    A a;
    a.b();
}
```